# Как проверить есть ли право на полный доступ у группы "Пользователи"?

Tags: c#

Мой код:

```
using (Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(@"CLSID\14D09604-FF91-43CF-B717-A5EF559A6167", RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree))
{
    RegistrySecurity rs = key.GetAccessControl(AccessControlSections.Access);
    SecurityIdentifier allUsers = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.BuiltinUsersSid, null);


    foreach (AuthorizationRule rule in rs.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(SecurityIdentifier)))
    {
        if (rule.IdentityReference.Value.Equals(allUsers.Value, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            if (((RegistryAccessRule)rule).AccessControlType == AccessControlType.Allow && ((RegistryAccessRule)rule).RegistryRights == RegistryRights.FullControl)
            {
                //всегда попадаю сюда, не зависимо от того есть права на ветку или нет
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Что делаю не так?

Answer (score 3):

Не правильно указал путь до CLSID индентификатора.
Нужно писать: `@"CLSID\\{14D09604-FF91-43CF-B717-A5EF559A6167}"`.